# EasyMock argument matcher

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I want to use EasyMock for testing. One of the service call takes an object. In my class that uses the service, the object is constructed inside my method. I can construct the object in the test beforehand but the object isn't the same one as in my class' method. To make EasyMock work, I have to use eq(). But unfortunately, the object class is part of the service's package and doesn't override Object.equal(). How can I work around this? There is something called custom argument matcher. Does it serve my purpose? Thank you.

Comment: How about I do want to verify the states of object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `eq()`. You can use any other matcher as well, such as `anyObject()`, `isA()`, `capture()` or `notNull()`.

Comment: capture() is what I am looking for. Much easier than custom argument matcher. Thanks JB.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the argument's state you could use `anyObject()`